# Question about the definition for zero morphism?

Tags: category-theory, definition

The following question is taken from $\textit{Categories}$ by Horst Schubert.

Let $C$ be a category, for each ordered pair of objects $(A,B)$ of $C$ a (possibly empty) set $[A,B]_C$ called the set of $\textit{morphisms}$ from $A$ to $B$.  If it is obvious from the context which category is meant, $[A,B]_C$ will be replaced by $[A,B].$

Let $C$ be a category with a zero object $0$.  if $A$ and $B$ are any objects, then there is exactly one morphism $A\rightarrow B$ which factors through $0$; i.e., it can be represented in the form $A\rightarrow 0\rightarrow B$.  We call it the $0-$ morphism and it is usual to denote it by $0$ (better $0_{A,B}$).  $0:A\rightarrow B$ does not depend on the choice of a zero object $0$ in $C$.  If $0'$ is another zero object, consider $A\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 0'\rightarrow B.$

Questions:
What do the following two maps mean, or rather what are they suppose to equal to?

$A \xrightarrow{\normalsize\textit{f}} 0\xrightarrow{\normalsize\textit{g}}B,$ $g\circ f=?$ 
$A \xrightarrow{\normalsize\textit{f'}} 0\xrightarrow{\normalsize\textit{g'}}0'\xrightarrow{\normalsize\textit{h'}}B,$ $h'\circ g'\circ f'=?$ (I assigned letters to the maps since it might be easier to refer to them individually.)

Also, how does one get from $0:A\rightarrow B$ to the compositional maps in the definition above?.  Lastly, what does it when a morphism factors through $0$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Some context is missing because in general, there may not be an arrow from $0$ to anything but itself.  For example, in the category with precisely 2 objects with precisely one non-identity arrow.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Can I ask what are the difference in meaning between the two notations:  $0\rightarrow B$ versus $0:A\rightarrow B$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @JasonDeVito. A category with precisely two objects and one non-identity arrow cannot have a zero object as its initial and terminal objects, even if they exist, are necessarily different. In categories that actually have a zero object, since the zero object is initial, there's always a unique arrow $0 \rightarrow X$ to any $X$

Comment: @Seth By definition $g \circ f$ is equal to the morphism $0_{A,B}$. Since the zero object $0$ is an initial obejct there is exactly one morphism $0 \rightarrow B$, and $h' \circ g'$ must be equal to that morphism, which you call $g$. Similary, since the zero object is terminal, there can be only one morphism $A \rightarrow 0$, so $f' = f$. Consequently  $h' \circ g' \circ f' = g \circ f' = g \circ f = 0_{A,B}$ as well. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Z.A.K.:  Oops, I was confusing $0$ object with terminal object.  You are right that my first comment was completely wrong.

Comment: @Z.A.K I am still confused about the difference between the notations: $0:A\rightarrow B$ versus $0\rightarrow B$ and $A\rightarrow 0$.  Also the identity $h'\circ g'\circ f'=g\circ f'=g\circ f=0_{A,B}$ means that $0:A\rightarrow B$ does not depend on the choice of a zero object $0$ in $C$, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, to say that $0$ is a zero object means that for any object $A$ in your category, there is a unique morphism $f_A:0\rightarrow A$ and a unique morphism $g_A:A\rightarrow 0$.

Now, suppose $A$ and $B$ are objects in your category.  If we select *some* zero object $0$, then we obtain a special morphism from $A$ to $B$:  the morphism $f_B\circ g_A$.

But what if we select another zero object $\hat{0}$?  Then we obtain another special morphism from $A$ to $B$:  $\hat{f}_B\circ \hat{g}_A$.

**Proposition:**  The two special morphisms from $A$ to $B$ are, in fact, the same.  That is, we have an equality $f_B\circ g_A = \hat{f}_B\circ \hat{g}_A$.

**Proof:**  Since $0$ is initial, we have a unique morphism $f_{\hat{0}}:0\rightarrow \hat{0}$.  The composition $\hat{f}_B\circ f_{\hat{0}}:0\rightarrow B$ is a morphism from $0$ to $B$.  Since there is a unique such morphism, we have $f_B = \hat{f}_B\circ f_{\hat{0}}.$

Likewise, we have a morphism $\hat{f}_0: \hat{0}\rightarrow 0$.  We similarly find that $g_A = \hat{f}_0 \circ \hat{g}_A$.

Thus, we have $f_B\circ g_A = \hat{f}_B\circ f_{\hat{0}} \circ \hat{f}_0\circ \hat{g}_A$.

But what is $f_{\hat{0}}\circ \hat{f}_0$?  Well, it is a morphism from $\hat{0}$ to $\hat{0}$.  Since $\hat{0}$ is a zero object, there is only one morphism from $\hat{0}$ to itself.  On the other hand, in any category, any object has an identity morphism from itself to itself.  Thus, by uniqueness of morphism $f_{\hat{0}}\circ \hat{f}_0 = 1_{\hat{0}}$, where $1$ denotes the identity morphism.

Putting this all together, we have $$f_B\circ g_A = \hat{f}_B\circ f_{\hat{0}} \circ \hat{f}_0\circ \hat{g}_A = \hat{f}_B\circ 1_{\hat{0}}\circ \hat{g}_A = \hat{f}_B\circ \hat{g}_A.$$

Thus, the proof is completed $\square$

Based on this proposition, we may unambiguously talk about "the" special morphism from $A$ to $B$:  simply select any zero object, and then form the composition $f_B\circ g_A$. Your book simply uses the notation $0_{A,B}:A\rightarrow B$ as the name of this composition.

As far as answering what the composition $f_B\circ g_A$ is equal to, that depends on the category.  For example, in the category of groups or in the category of rings, $0_{A,B}$ is the constant function which sends every element of $A$ to the (additive) identity of $B$.  In the category of pointed topological spaces, $0_{A,B}$ is the constant function which sends every element of $A$ to the "special" point of $B$.

But also keep in mind that objects in a category don't need to have elements, and the morphisms don't need to be functions in the usual sense.  So, in general, answering what $0_{A,B}$ *is*, the best answer one can give is the recipe above:  $0_{A,B}$ is the composition $f_B\circ g_A$ where $0$ is any zero object, and where $f_B:0\rightarrow B$ and $g_A:A\rightarrow 0$ are the unique morphisms one obtains from the definition of zero object.

I also wanted to address your last comment: what does it mean for a morphism to factor through something.  Here is the official definition:  Suppose $A,B,$ and  $C$ are objects of some category and $h:A\rightarrow B$ is a morphism.  Then $h$ is said to *factor through* C if there are morphisms $g:A\rightarrow C$ and $f:C\rightarrow B$ with the property that $h = f\circ g$.

Thus, $0_{A,B}$ factors through $0$ by definition (taking $f = f_B$ and $g= g_A$).

Comment: can I ask how do you remember what $0\rightarrow A$ and $B\rightarrow 0$ suppose to be.  I often see them and they are not assign name/letters as maps.  So say $0\xrightarrow{f} A$ and $B\xrightarrow{g} 0$.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by "supposed to be."  For some categories, $f$ and $g$ have nice descriptions, but what would an acceptable answer look like for a general category?  Instead, I just think of them as being given by the definition of 0 object.

Comment: when you say o object, do you mean when you see $0\rightarrow A$, you expect to see $B\rightarrow 0$ also.  Meaning, they often come in pairs when appearing in definition.  I have seen both morphisms in exact sequences and theory of modules.  Actually, abstract algebra beyond basic group theory, these type of morphisms make an appearance.  I have seen algebra texts having these two morphisms without explicit reference to category theory.  That is why I want to know how you remember what they mean independent of category theory.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I do almost no category theory (hence my totally incorrect initial comment on your post!)  I only see $0\rightarrow A$ or $B\rightarrow 0$ in the context of exact sequences of modules, where the map is the obvious one: think of $0$ as the $0$-module (where the only element is $0$).  Then the only module homomorphism $0\rightarrow A$ is the one which maps $0$ to the $0$-element of $A$.  When I say "object" I just mean "thing in a category".  When I see $0\rightarrow A$, whether I expect to see $B\rightarrow 0$ depends on the context.

Comment: I am surprised to hear you say you do almost no category theory.  I thought every mathematican who has not retired or in a nursing home had to learn the subject or at least gone through an intro text in it or seen such equivalent amount in a homological algebra/algebraic topology course.  I mean even if you don't like it, you will be subject to it if it means dragging you kicking and screaming.

Comment: As someone who uses quite a bit of "classical" algebraic topology (homotopy groups, homology and cohomology groups of smooth manifolds), I do find the language of category theory useful to express certain ideas.  E.g., the fact that we associate algebraic invariants to topological spaces in conta/covariant ways is quite important.  But I have never thought about a "zero object" in the context of my work.  Of course, the trivial group, ring, module, etc comes up a lot, but these examples are sufficiently concrete that I always have a definition map $0\rightarrow A$ or $A\rightarrow 0$ in mind.

Comment: And there are many other branches of mathematics (e.g. combinatorics or graph theory), where I think most practicing mathematicians use no category theory on a day-to-day basis.  A lot of analysis/PDEs doesn't use it either.

Comment: if you need to know what a coequalizer/product/coproduct, etc for a category with a particular structure, do you just look it up or ask someone?  I mean if you ever need it in your learning/reading for research purposes?

Comment: also, is category theory best learn in a specific subject context, like in algebraic topology/homological algebra/grad algebra instead of going through an intro text in category theory?  i mean, what has been your experience seeing how others best learn this subject.  I should preface about learning it for the purpose of being able to understand terms from category theory and understand how they are used and not specializing in it.

Comment: Yep!  Wikipedia and nlab together are great resources. And, for example, I can't tell you what a coequalizer is.  As far as product and coproduct, I have a 50/50 shot of getting both definitions right or both wrong ;-).  If I really need it, I'd google it or use examples (e.g, I know that in the category of sets, product means the usual notion of product.  That's enough for me to figure out the definitions if I need to.)

Comment: As far as how it's best learned, that seems like a highly personal question I don't feel capable of answering.  I will say that what you need to learn regarding category theory is directly related to the kind of math you're generally interested in.  If you want do to (many kinds of) graph theory, you probably need essentially none.  If you want to conduct research within category theory, you need a ton.  Plenty of analysts and geometers use very little.  Algebraic topologists use some, algebraic geometers seem to use significantly more, etc.

Comment: I want to go into either algebraic/analytic number theory.  I see people recommending Hartshorne's text, and that contains category theory.  So I thought i would see what all the buzz is about.  I am about to regret my decision very very much.  For every concept, there are like ten more new terms, and depending on how old the books you are looking at, some of those same terms are not even talk about in the older texts, or they might call it differently, etc.  All of the books i have seen, the index are atrociously bad.  I expected a lot of different terms/concepts.definitions...

Comment: have been standardized.  Was I ever in for a rude awakening.  I really appreciate you taking the time out to answer my question.  Your answer is crystal clear.  I can't say the same for some of the category theory text I am studying from.

Comment: I'm sorry - I know almost noting about those fields.  Do you have friends/an advisor you can talk to regarding how much category theory you need?  Alternatively, you could try to ask a question here, but it may be closed as too broad.  In grad school, I did try to learn some algebraic geometry from Hartshorne's book and really struggled.  You may have better luck with books by others.

Comment: I am just learning category theory on my own.  I am two third of my way through my undergrad.  Also, sometimes I lurk on math twitter, there are a bunch of folks there who are into homotopy type theory,/algebraic geometry,/low dim top etc ,etc.  Whenever they talk about math, it is always in the language of category theory.